# How i can delete Evolution email completely?

Tags: evolution

Reason is i have configured my official account in Evolution last day and and it stuckedup, then i tried to reconfigure its not working even the removed account is showing SEND& RECV

Pls help ma friends

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge evolution
```